# Smarty ignores cache_id?

Tags: php, caching, smarty

since I have dynamic elements in some of the sites I want to Cache with smarty, I figgured I would use the second parameter of smarty [isCached](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.is.cached.tpl)() function with an Id like "parameter1.parameter2.parameter3".
But for some reason smarty caches only once and then delivers the same page ignoring the parameters and dynamic content.

What could be the source of my problem?

Code:

.tpl file:

`extends file="1_layout.tpl"}

{block name=title}domain.com - index{/block}

{block name=content} <html here> {/block}`

.php file:

```
$view = new Smarty(); 
$view->caching = true; 

$id = "index_"; 
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){ 
   $id .= "loggedIn";
}else{
   $id .= "guest"; 
} 
$id .= $_COOKIE['filter']; 

if(!$view->isCached('1_index.tpl', $id)) {
   get and assign some data
} 

$view->display('1.index.tpl');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the code  you are using

Comment: Thanks. The .tpl looks like 
`{extends file="1_layout.tpl"}

{block name=title}domain.com - index{/block}

{block name=content}

<html here>

{/block}`

The .php looks like 

`$view = new Smarty();

$view->caching = true;

$id = "index_";
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $id .= "loggedIn";
}else{
    $id .= "guest";
}
$id .= $_COOKIE['filter'];

echo $id;

if(!$view->isCached('1_index.tpl', $id))
{get some data}

$view->display('1.index.tpl');`

Comment: can you edit it into your question? The line breaks get lost which makes the code hard to read

Comment: You are 100% sure `$_COOKIE['filter']`  contains something?

Comment: Yes, when i echo the $id it cahnges like it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the cache ID to the display call as well.

```
$view->display('1.index.tpl', $id);
```